# Storing heavy content client side

Tags: html, web

I have designed a gaming website which loads up lots of images and sound. However, in India the average internet speed is only few hundred kb/s which causes a significant delay and jittery gaming experience. Is it possible to store these media files (approx 100 MB) on client computer so that while the rest of the lighter stuff is served by the server the heavy duty stuff is pulled from client's computer hard disk?

The maximum storage that we can get through Cookies/HTML5 is around few KB/5 MB only. So I am not able to find a viable solution.

Comment: I know that [Runescape](http://runescape.com/) uses large map and stores some files locally (I haven't checked the size). But I'm not sure how they're doing now (they were announcing HTML5 revamp), but in the past, they've used java. So you might want to look into java or flash storages. I know it loses whole purpose of HTML5 game because users have to install plugins, but you'll have to do a compromise between first-timer user experience and recurring user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If these are static media resources, just make sure your server is telling clients (and proxies) to cache them. Ideally, put a very long (1-year) lifetime on them and use versions in the name if they'll ever need to be updated.

Comment: I don't think this solves long loading time due to slow connection on client side.

Comment: @maremp There's no way to avoid the first load, period.